# 2 react components within existing html document

Tags: reactjs

This question has been asked however the solutions don't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

I have two react components that have been compiled and preprocessed to JS files. I reference each file within a script tag within my existing HTML document.

Only 1 component loads. Both work independently. It will only render/load the first script tag.

How do I get both components to render?

Path: `index.html`

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div id="progress_bar"></div>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
  </body>

  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="progress_bar.js"></script>
  <script src="like_button.js"></script>
</html>
```

Path: `Progressbar.js` (this is preprocessed to a JS file)

```
class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, this is a component</div>;
  }
}

const domContainer = document.getElementById("progress_bar");
ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBar />, domContainer);
```

Path: `like_button.js`

```
"use strict";

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return "You liked this.";
    }

    return e(
      "button",
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      "Like"
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.getElementById("like_button_container");
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: no errors in console.

Comment: Possible this will help - https://medium.jonasbandi.net/hosting-multiple-react-applications-on-the-same-document-c887df1a1fcd